# Spring boot 1.5.2.RELEASE : Rolling File logging

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot

I have the below config in `application.yml`

```
logging:
  path: logs/
  file: logs/service.log
  pattern:
      console: "%d %-5level %logger : %msg%n"
      file: "%d %-5level [%thread] %logger : %msg%n"
  level:
      com.demo.api: INFO
```

below is my `logback.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    </root>
    <logger name="com.demo" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

when I run the spring boot application its not logging to file but I see the below logging in console as below

```
2017-06-07 16:14:45.841  INFO 37084 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] c.d.api.Controller        : test msg 1
2017-06-07 16:14:45.854  INFO 37084 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] c.d.api.dao.Dao  : test msg 2
2017-06-07 16:14:49.188  INFO 37084 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] c.d.api.service.DigSigService   : test msg 3
2017-06-07 16:14:49.199  INFO 37084 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] c.d.api.service.DigSigService   : test msg 4
2017-06-07 16:14:49.200  INFO 37084 --- [nio-8443-exec-8] c.d.api.dao.Dao  : test msg 5
```

I tried updating the `logback.xml` as below but still no lock with logging to file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/logs" />

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<appender name="FILE-ERROR"
    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>${DEV_HOME}/error.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/error.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                    </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
    </rollingPolicy>

</appender>

<!-- Send logs to both console and file audit -->
<logger name="com.demo.api" level="debug"
    additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
</logger>

<root level="error">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE-ERROR" />
</root>

</configuration>
```

can someone please help me with fixing the logging to rolling file?

Comment: You need to enter an absolute path for `logging.path` like for Ex: `C:/User/Projects/YourProject/logs`. Secondly make sure that the `logback.xml` file is in your Classpath: `If you put a logback.xml in the root of your classpath it will be picked up from there (or logback-spring.xml to take advantage of the templating features provided by Boot)`

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `logback.xml` located, directly in the resources folder? If so, this should work right away (just tested your config, it works). If not, you have to specify where it is located. E.g. if it is under `...resources/config`, you have to add the following entry to the `application.yml`:

```
logging:
  config: classpath:config/logback.xml
```